# Why hibernate generates unnecessary constraint?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having a strange problem with the SQL generated by a bidirectional relationship in Hibernate. Here's the code.

First the `@OneToMany` side:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "employers")
public class Employer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "eid")
    private Long employerId;
    
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "titleId")
    private Set<Title> titles = new TreeSet<>(); 
    
    // Getters/setters...
}
```

And the `@ManyToOne` side:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "titles")
public class Title {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "tid")
    private long titleId;
    
    /**
     * Not sure if I need a bi-directional relation here.
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employerId")
    private Employer employer;

    // Getters/setters...
}
```

I'm fairly new to springboot and hibernate, so this is the first thing I've attempted that would actually run.  Based on the tutorials and the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation) I've referenced, the SQL generated in my case is wrong.

Here's the generated SQL (`Postgres9Dialect`)

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.items
(
    item_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('items_item_id_seq'::regclass),
    text character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    title_tid bigint,
    CONSTRAINT items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (item_id),
    CONSTRAINT fkkwhqrl3vscoqcacws6kgsdlx5 FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
        REFERENCES public.titles (tid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkluhgxmnakeuroph186b2k05eq FOREIGN KEY (title_tid)
        REFERENCES public.titles (tid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

The problem is this constraint:

```sql
CONSTRAINT fkkwhqrl3vscoqcacws6kgsdlx5 FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
REFERENCES public.titles (tid) MATCH SIMPLE
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION
   ON DELETE NO ACTION,
```

It has the effect of not allowing additional titles from being created if the title id (`tid`) exceeds the highest number of employer ids (eid in the employer table).  The generated employers table is correct.

If I delete this constraint manually, then it works as expected.

Why is it creating this erroneous constraint?  What am I missing?

(as an aside, title refers to a title one would have for a particular employer, not a book title, so I am not trying to combine employer & author tutorials)

Comment: You show the schema for table `items` that is not referenced in the source code anywhere. Can you please clarify why you thinkk that this table causes the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should correct your mapping in this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employers")
public class Employer {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer")
    private Set<Title> titles = new TreeSet<>(); 
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "titles")
public class Title {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employerId")
    private Employer employer;
    // ...
}
```

The `mappedBy` should hold the field name of another side of association.